# Issues with PiVPN and UFW

Tags: networking

Hi I just installed the latest pi os on my pi 3 B+. I installed pihole, pivpn and ufw.

If I leave ufw inactive pivpn works but if I enable ufw I am getting the following blocks in logs and I can't for the life of me come up with a rule that will allow the traffic and work.

Can anyone help?

here is the log from ufw.

Jun 20 18:04:43 RPi316 kernel: [27280.107991] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wg0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.97.x.x DST=17.248.x.x LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49996 DPT=443 WINDOW=65xxx RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Jun 20 18:05:00 RPi316 kernel: [27296.660179] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wg0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.97.x.x DST=40.99.x.x LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49997 DPT=443 WINDOW=65xxx RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: what rules have you tried? `DPT=443` suggests https coming in wg0 and out eth0 is being blocked - but you haven't shown your ufw config ... so